# Evaluating $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}/B_{r_{0}}(0)}\frac{1}{|x|}dx$

Tags: limits

I want to evaluate

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}/B_{r_{0}}(0)}\frac{1}{|x|}dx.$$

**Attempt**

We have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n/B_{r_0}(0)}\frac{1}{|x|}dx=\int_{r_{0}}^{\infty}r \, dr =\infty.$$

So I guess

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}/B_{r_0}(0)}\frac{1}{|x|} \, dx =\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t} \infty=\infty$$

and not $1$.

If so, I want to understand the intuition behind

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_{r_{0}}^{\infty}r=\infty.$$

One guess is that the limit of $\frac{\infty}{t}$ as $t\to \infty$ is still infinity because $\frac{\infty}{t}=\infty$ for all t.

Otherwise it is like saying $\frac{\infty}{2}>\frac{\infty}{3}$ which makes no sense.

Comment: where does $t$ enter in the integral?

Comment: there is no t in the integral, see comment above.

Comment: so would you like to at least make $r_0$ depend on $t$? For example $r_0=1/t^a$ for some $a>0$.

Comment: no, $r_{0}$ is just a constant. My confusion is very basic.

Comment: Then the limit is infinity since for each $t$ it's infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any $a$,
$$
\lim_{t \to a} \infty = \infty
$$
Your limit is simply the special case $a = \infty$.